# Unable to use package "golang.org/x/oauth2" to authenticate with facebook: "Missing redirect_uri parameter"

Tags: facebook, go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This code works:

```
func handleFacebookCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    state := r.FormValue("state")
    if state != oauthStateString {
        fmt.Printf("invalid oauth state, expected '%s', got '%s'\n", oauthStateString, state)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    code := r.FormValue("code")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    Url, err := url.Parse(oauthConf.Endpoint.TokenURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
    }
    parameters := url.Values{}
    parameters.Add("client_id", oauthConf.ClientID)
    parameters.Add("client_secret", oauthConf.ClientSecret)
    parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:9090/oauth2callback")
    parameters.Add("code", code)
    Url.RawQuery = parameters.Encode()
    resp, err := http.Get(Url.String())

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Get: %s\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
```

But when I replace the part below the marker `//////...` with:

```
    token, err := oauthConf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("oauthConf.Exchange() failed with '%s'\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
```

I get:

> oauthConf.Exchange() failed with 'oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad
>   Request Response: {"error":{"message":"Missing redirect_uri
>   parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":191,"fbtrace_id":"XXXX"}}'

Is the package `golang.org/x/oauth2` unable to exchange a `code` for a `token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was missing. I apparently need to add the `RedirectURL`field in the `oauthConfig` struct to get `Exchange()` to work properly. This is not the case for Slack or GitHub but apparently FB is slightly more picky.

```
var oauthConf = &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:9090/oauth2callback", /* Fixed! */
        Scopes:       []string{"public_profile"},
        Endpoint:     facebook.Endpoint,
    }
```